# First five non-numeric, non-null, distinct values from a column

Tags: pandas

How to get the first five non-numeric, non-null, distinct values from a column?

For example, given the table as follows

```
col1 
=====
n1 
1        
2        
n2
n3
n3
n4
n5
n5
n6
None
```

I want to get

```
 col1 
=====
n1       
n2
n3
n4
n5
```

Comment: Loop through and use regex?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.to_numeric` to force the non-NaN to `NaN` and then invert the mask and select the first 5 unique values:

```
In [9]:
df.loc[df.index.difference(pd.to_numeric(df['col1'], errors='coerce').dropna().index),'col1'].unique()[:5]

Out[9]:
array(['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['n1', '1', '2', 'n2', 'n3', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5', 'n5', 'n6','None']})
```

- remove string `NaN` and `None` by `replace`
- remove numeric by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)
- remove duplicates by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html)
- get first 5 values by [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.head.html)
- if necessary `reset_index` for monotonic increasing index

```
df = df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df.col1.replace({'None':1, 'NaN':1}), 
                          errors='coerce').isnull(), 'col1']
       .drop_duplicates()
       .head(5)
       .reset_index(drop=True)

print (df)
0    n1
1    n2
2    n3
3    n4
4    n5
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Another possible solution:

```
df = pd.Series(df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df.col1
                        .replace({'None':1, 'NaN':1}), errors='coerce').isnull(), 'col1']
      .unique()[:5])
print (df)
0    n1
1    n2
2    n3
3    n4
4    n5
dtype: object
```

---

But if mixed values - numeric with `strings`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['n1', 1, 1, 'n2', 'n3', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5', 'n5', 'n6', None]})

df = pd.Series(df.loc[df.col1.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)), 'col1']
       .unique()[:5])

print (df)
0    n1
1    n2
2    n3
3    n4
4    n5
dtype: object
```

Comment: both answers are correct & good, but I find this a lot easier to walk through in my head.